# Restoring a Lookup(information already on this site) Value in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, nintex-workflow

I have a list in sharepoint (List B) which has a column value that is a look up(information already on this site) from List A.

In attempt to connect list A to a database, the data was deleted from list A and then restored..

That being said; List A is populated and correct, but now List B is blank in that particular look up column..

Does anyone have any suggestions of ways to restore that particular column value??

Comment: When the data was deleted, was the entire list deleted or just the data within?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that when trying to connect list A to a database it actually deleted all items and then reinserted them.  Therefore the lookup column in list B was pointing to the old metadata for that particular column.

I ended up deleting the data that had been 'reinserted' in list A ,then restored the previous list A column values from the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for but might be better than nothing.

Do you have any columns to match the items? Something along the line of "If ListB Item has x in column xc then the corresponding looked up item has y in column yc". If so you could repopulate the list with a powershell script like:

```
asnp *share*
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c") | Out-Null
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

$webUrl = "<your Url>"
$listBTitle = "<Title of list B>"
$listATitle = "<Title of list A>"

$listBLookUpColumnName = "<lookup Column name in list b>"
$listAValueToShow = "<Column name of the value that should be displayed in the lookup field>"

$matchColumnA = "<Title of match column list A>"
$matchColumnB = "<Title of match column list B>"

$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$listB = $web.Lists[$listBTitle]
$listA = $web.Lists[$listATitle]

$listB.Items | % {
$lookingItem = $_
$itemToLookIn = $listA.Items | ? { $_[$matchColumnA] -eq $lookingItem[$matchColumnB] }

$lookUpValue = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldLookupValue
$lookUpValue.LookupId = $itemToLookIn.ID
$lookUpValue.LookupValue = $itemToLookIn[$listAValueToShow]

$lookingItem[$listBLookUpColumnName] = $lookUpValue

$lookingItem.Update()
}
```

If not, is version control activated in ListB? Maybe write a script to revert the items 1 version back or read the lookup value from a previous version if some other work has been done with the items.